# Identify if an Android tablet has a sim card slot

Tags: android, sim-card

Is there a way to check, from within my application, if a tablet has a sim card slot?

My requirement is to find out if a tablet is a Wifi only or a Wifi + Cellular unit. 
I checked the earlier links provided on Stack Overflow for this, and none of them seem to be working for my device. The Wifi only unit returns a `TYPE_MOBILE` under the network info. Both the Wifi and Cellular units return a `PHONE_TYPE_NONE` and `SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN` hence even those checks are not applicable.

The IMEI returned is also null in both the cases. If there is a valid sim card inserted inside the sim card slot then I can validate if the unit is a cellular unit, but if the cellular unit has no sim card inserted, or if the sim card slot is bad, then I am unable to distinguish between a cellular and a wifi + cellular unit

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);  //gets the current TelephonyManager
if (tm.getSimState() != TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT){
  //the device has a sim card
} else {
  //no sim card available
}
```

[source](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/check-if-sim-card-exists-in-the-phone)

Comment: This works if my device has a sim card. What about the use-case if the sim slot is a bad one and does not detect the sim card. Would this check still work ?

Comment: This doesn't check for the slot, it only checks whether a sim card is inserted.

Comment: okay so in case there is a bad sim slot then it would not consider this to be a cellular unit right ?

Comment: Actually this does not work for the wifi only Kindble tablet that I have. it enters the first check showing that this device has a sim card which is not supposed to happen

Answer (score 0):

You can check network interfaces supported by the device. Then you can use the [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) to check if your device supports mobile data connection.

```java
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
if (cm != null) {
    if (cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) != null) {
        // the device can use mobile networks
    }
}
```